# Is there any way QML can load data using Facebook Javascript SDK?

Tags: facebook, qt, facebook-graph-api, qml, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to get QML to interact with FB graph API using FB Javascript SDK.

I'm loading this HTML inside a WebView element:

```
 html: "<script>console.log(\"This is in WebKit!\"); window.FB.init();</script>"
```

and I've also created a JS Window Object named FB inside the WebView:

```
 javaScriptWindowObjects: QtObject {
          WebView.windowObjectName: "FB"
      }
```

But as soon as the window.FB.init() is called, it throws out an error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: window
```

Another approach I'm using is load the FB.init() function using Component.onComplete

```
     function startupFunction() {
         console.log("This call is in QML!");
         FB.init({
                         appId:'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', cookie:true,
                         status:true
                      });
         console.log(FB);
         }
    Component.onCompleted: startupFunction();
```

But I get the error as :

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'FB.init' [undefined] is not a function
```

Here is the complete QML:

```
import QtQuick 1.0
import "fb.js" as FB
import QtWebKit 1.0
Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text {
        text: "Hello World"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

    }
    WebView {
         preferredWidth: 490
         preferredHeight: 400
         scale: 0.5
         smooth: false

         javaScriptWindowObjects: QtObject {
                  WebView.windowObjectName: "FB"
              }
         html: "<script>console.log(\"This is in WebKit!\"); window.FB.init();</script>"

         function startupFunction() {
             console.log("This call is in QML!");
             FB.init({
                             appId:'xxxxxxxxxxxx', cookie:true,
                             status:true
                          });
             console.log(FB);
             }
        Component.onCompleted: startupFunction();
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not defining anything in your window-object, your `QtObject` just contains the `windowObjectName` but no functions or vars. `windowObjectName` is really just the name for the new object, qml does not use the `"fb.js"`-import for that object.

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qml-webview.html#javaScriptWindowObjects-prop) it's supposed to look like this:

```
WebView {
   javaScriptWindowObjects: QtObject {
     WebView.windowObjectName: "FB"

     // the stuff you want in that window-object goes here:
     function init() {
         console.log("FB.init");
     }
   }
}
```